# Image inserted on site, text/information popup on hover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie and had an idea for a site, but I need some help. I believe I'll be using Bootstrap 3 so I can quickly get it up and running without much hassle.

I'm going to be inserting an image and then on certain spots on that image, I want text/information to show when you hover over that point. Remember when Bing had something similar?

If you need more information, let me know. Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help me.